# Heroku Deployment Error *heroku open* command Clojure app

Tags: heroku, clojure, web-deployment

Hi i am trying to deploy my project i develop in Clojure to heroku. it created and build too but

when i write *heroku open* it gives error and logs saying missing build

[image: This is my project structure project file is empty]

[image: This is error i am getting]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text and source and errors.  We can not search in them and can not copy from them.

Comment: : State changed from starting to crashed
2020-07-16T08:22:35.116941+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-07-16T08:22:43.836021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run build && npm start -- --port $pacific-caverns-88597`
2020-07-16T08:22:47.350980+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: build

Comment: above is error when i build its scceeded but when i open it gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using heroky "autodetect" and it's detecting your npm file and trying to start it as a npm project.

You need to specify to use clojure buildpack in somewhere inside heroku settings.

I recommend you to move into "docker mode" in heroku, that will give you more control about how to build/run your project.